# Why I cannot render AJAX JSON value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="value in RandomTopic" :key="value.id">{{ value.title }}</li>
</ul>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      RandomTopic: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     ///some method to get data from remote server
     console.log(res.data);
     this.RandomTopic = res.data;
  }
}
```

I want to render all the data from the remote server in front end. However, after the program ran, it reports this error:

```
Cannot set property 'RandomTopic' of undefined ; at api request success callback function
TypeError: Cannot set property 'RandomTopic' of undefined
```

The `console.log(res.data);` log the `JSON` successfully so it seems not the problem of AJAX or remote server.

And also, here is a sample of the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 421,
        "title": "sample1",
        "image_url": "bus.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 535,
        "title": "sample78",
        "image_url": "car.png"
    }
]
```

What's wrong with my code ? I am a beginner of Vue 3, please help me.

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The error can't be produced by this code.

Comment: A likely cause for such error is that a callback was used the wrong way in the part that was omitted, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error you mentioned, Issue is basically related to the scope of `this`. Looks like you are using regular function instead of arrow function `( => {...})` which don't provide their own this binding (it retains this value of the enclosing lexical context).

*Reference -* [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
.then(res => {
    this.RandomTopic = res.data;
})
```